# CS50 Tideman code passes check50 fully but isn't printing the winner correctly

Tags: c, cs50

I've just "finished" tideman, and although check50 passes me, it's definitely not printing the winners correctly.  Has anyone else had this issue?

This is my print winner code -

```
// Print the winner of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    //array of total "trues" in locked[i][j] by candidate i.e. total edges
    int sum_source[candidate_count]; 
    int source;

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i ++)
    {
        source = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j ++)
        {
            if (locked[i][j] == true)
            {   
                source ++;
            }    
        sum_source[j] = source;    
        }
        // sum_source[i] = source; I thought sum_source should come here to sum by candidate i 
        //but this causes check 50 to fail print winner when pairs tied
    }

    int max_source = sum_source[candidate_count - 1]; //sets max number of trues by candidate to last candidate

    for (int k = 0; k < candidate_count - 1; k ++)
    {
        if (sum_source[k] > max_source) //reset max_trues for higher number of trues
        {
            max_source = sum_source[k];
        }
    } 


    for (int l = 0; l < candidate_count; l ++)
    {
        if (sum_source[l] == max_source)
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[l]); //print all candidates with number of trues = max_source as winners
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

My output is as follows:
For some reason it's printing after every vote and just printing out the votes.
Correct output in this case should just be "a" however check50 is passing me.

:) print_winner prints winner of election when one candidate wins over all others
:) print_winner prints winner of election when some pairs are tied
To see the results in your browser go to https://submit.cs50.io/check50/26f6f9fe89617259dc60658b35957549f52a8e2a

~/pset3/tideman/ $ ./tideman a b c

Number of voters: 2

Rank 1: a

Rank 2: b

Rank 3: c

a

b

c

Rank 1: a

Rank 2: b

Rank 3: c

a

b

c

Any ideas why check50 is not failing me and also what I'm doing wrong in code that's causing printing after each vote and not actually printing winner?

Comment: Provide a [mre] including a complete statement of the requirements.

Comment: I am super confused. The code passes check50 tests, but it does not print the winner but it prints all candidates?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could get away with a simpler approach. Since what you are looking for is just the candidate whose column in **locked** has only *false* values (no one won against him). And since c stores boolean values as 0 and 1, that is like saying that the total sum of the column equals 0.
You can easily test it like this:

```
// Print the winner of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    // Create an array of int called sum and populate it with zeroes
    int sum[candidate_count];
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        sum[i] = 0;
    }
    // Take the cumsum of each column and return the winner as soon as it's 0
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i ++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j ++)
        {
            sum[i] += locked[j][i];
        }
        if (sum[i] == 0)
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[i]);
            return;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```